# Failed to deploy business network archive: not found

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm following the [Hyperledger Developer Tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/developer-tutorial) and I set up my development environment using the [instructions they provided](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/development-tools.html).

After that, these are the steps I followed:

1. I created the peer admin card, using the fabric tools script.
2. I installed the composer runtime: `composer runtime install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --businessNetworkName e-wallet`
3. I try to deploy the business network archive: `composer network start --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --archiveFile ./e-wallet@0.0.1.bna --file networkadmin.card`

But unfortunately this step fails. I receive this error in the client:

```
Error: Error trying to instantiate composer runtime. Error: Error: Invalid results returned ::NOT_FOUND
Command failed
```

This is the log output from the peer:

```
2018-02-12 13:34:24.964 UTC [eventhub_producer] validateEventMessage -> DEBU 22e ValidateEventMessage starts for signed event 0xc42037cf30
2018-02-12 13:34:24.970 UTC [eventhub_producer] registerHandler -> DEBU 22f registering event type: BLOCK
2018-02-12 13:34:25.021 UTC [eventhub_producer] validateEventMessage -> DEBU 230 ValidateEventMessage starts for signed event 0xc42037d380
2018-02-12 13:34:25.023 UTC [eventhub_producer] deRegisterHandler -> DEBU 231 deregistering event type: BLOCK
2018-02-12 13:34:25.036 UTC [eventhub_producer] Chat -> ERRO 232 error during Chat, stopping handler: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
```

I got stuck debugging this at the following questions:

1. How do I know what "not found" relates to?
2. What is networkadmin.card, and should that be created already or is this command creating it? I tried to look for this detail in the tutorial but must be missing it.

Many thanks!

Comment: 1) what Operating system and version? 
2) You don't actually say whether you downloaded and started the Fabric environment in your sequence,  but I assume its true as you seem to indicate that the `composer runtime install` ran ok - is that correct?
3) did you install the pre-requisites successfully -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/next/installing/installing-prereqs.html
4) what does your peer log show

Comment: Hey Paul, thanks for the comment.

1) OS X 10.13.2
2) I downloaded the docker images and successfully launched them via the docker-compose file (using the fabric-tools script)
3) Yes
4) The peer log is posted above

Comment: the developer tutorial uses 'tutorial-network' as an example, and from start to finish we know that works (as several thousand have used it). The network name in your package.json file MUST match the name of the runtime install that you used. (it does in the tutorial). Have you changed anything else - did you reset your peer by any chance (the log doesn't tell me much) - I would suggest to do a teardown of you dev environment, remove your cards in $HOME/.composer (rm -rf) - important - and start your Fabric and run createPeerAdminCard.sh  -  try the tutorial-network example as-is again,.

Comment: Sure, I can definitely do that. Although I think it would add value to work out how to debug this properly. Otherwise it doesn't bode well for figuring out issues when an application is live down the line.

Comment: Is there a way to get access to more detailed logs or enable a debug mode? 100% agree that the issue will be on my end.